# View the source of an builtin R package

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [View the source of an R package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788779/view-the-source-of-an-r-package)

I want to see the source code of stats::reorder.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788779/view-the-source-of-an-r-package) seems not apply to built in packages which are compiled to bytecode:

```
> stats::reorder
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("reorder")
>bytecode: 0x103321718<
>environment: namespace:stats<
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with reorder being compiled to bytecode and everything to do with it being a generic function.

My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173683/how-can-i-read-the-code-for-summary-for-a-data-frame/11173734#11173734) elaborates on this.

But specifically for this situation if you want to see the code you can use

```c
# Find what methods are available for reorder
methods(reorder)
# Attempt to check out the code for reorder.default
reorder.default
# Use getAnywhere to view code regardless of if it is exported
getAnywhere(reorder.default)
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you want `methods(reorder)`. But for your mode general question, the best way is to download the source code of R, and search the code with `grep`. You can also browse the code [online](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/stats) but it's not always obvious in which file a particular function might live.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a matter of compilation, what you're seeing is the result of the fact that `reorder` is written to do different things depending on the class of what you want to reorder. There are separate reorder functions for different possible options, and you can list them by calling `methods(reorder)`. You can then examine the source of whichever one is appropriate.