# Convert date to year-quarter format

Tags: r, date, date-format

I have a bunch of dates that are of the format `yyyy-mm-dd` and I would like to convert them to a `yyyy-q` format where `qq` is the quarter of the year (so months 1, 2, 3 map to q=1 and 4, 5, 6 map to q=2, etc.).  I use the following function to accomplish this:

```
get_month <- function(d) { return(as.numeric(format(d, "%m")))}
get_qtr <- function(d) {
f <- function(m) {
    if (m %in% c(1,2,3)) { return(1) }
    else if (m %in% c(4,5,6)) { return(2) }
    else if (m %in% c(7,8,9)) { return(3) }
    else if (m %in% c(10,11,12)) { return(4) }
}
m <- get_month(d)
r <- sapply(m, f)
return(r)
}
```

This is, however, very slow.  Is there a faster way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `yearqtr` in the zoo package.

```
> as.yearqtr(Sys.Date())
[1] "2012 Q4"
```

Comment: great, thank you. how do i look at the source of what it is doing? when i type:

Comment: > zoo:::as.yearqtr
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("as.yearqtr")
<environment: namespace:zoo>

Comment: @Alex: See [View the source of an R package](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788779/view-the-source-of-an-r-package).

Comment: yep, i took a look at that earlier but it just says to type in what i already typed in. that is `zoo:::as.yearqtr`

Comment: @Alex: the last answer to that question tells you how to proceed.  Answers to [How to examine the code of a function in R that's object class sensitive](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1439348/271616) (which was linked to in one of the answers in my previous link) are also very good.