# Package TSclust in R, What is the definition of SAX.breakpoints.table function

Tags: r, function, package, tsclust

There is a function called `MINDIST.SAX` in package [TSclust](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TSclust/TSclust.pdf). Here is the body of the function:

```
require(TSclust)
> MINDIST.SAX
function (x, y, alpha, n) 
{
    w <- length(x)
    symb <- SAX.breakpoints.table(alpha)
    d <- 0
    for (i in 1:w) {
        xi <- x[i]
        yi <- y[i]
        if (abs(xi - yi) > 1) {
            d <- d + (symb[max(xi, yi)] - symb[min(xi, yi) + 
                1])^2
        }
    }
    sqrt((n/w) * d)
}
<environment: namespace:TSclust>
```

As  can be seen above, there is another function called `SAX.breakpoints.table` that has been re-called.

I need to know the exact definition of this function (i.e. `SAX.breakpoints.table`). I tried `SAX.breakpoints.table`

```
> SAX.breakpoints.table
Error: object 'SAX.breakpoints.table' not found
```

as well as:

```
> ls("package:TSclust")
 [1] "cluster.evaluation"    "convert.to.SAX.symbol" "diss"                  "diss.ACF"             
 [5] "diss.AR.LPC.CEPS"      "diss.AR.MAH"           "diss.AR.PIC"           "diss.CDM"             
 [9] "diss.CID"              "diss.COR"              "diss.CORT"             "diss.DTWARP"          
[13] "diss.DWT"              "diss.EUCL"             "diss.FRECHET"          "diss.INT.PER"         
[17] "diss.MINDIST.SAX"      "diss.NCD"              "diss.PACF"             "diss.PDC"             
[21] "diss.PER"              "diss.PRED"             "diss.SPEC.GLK"         "diss.SPEC.ISD"        
[25] "diss.SPEC.LLR"         "loo1nn.cv"             "MINDIST.SAX"           "PAA"                  
[29] "pvalues.clust"
```

But I couldn't find it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>TSclust:::SAX.breakpoints.table
function (n) 
{
    qnorm(0:n/n)
}
<environment: namespace:TSclust>
```

This question, [view source code in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485228/view-source-code-in-r), will help for viewing any function within a package, even the hidden ones.

Hope this helps