# R .Internal for Beginners

Tags: r

I am new to R and I ran into a piece of code that I do not understand.  More specifically, I would like to know what `.Internal` does.  Here is an example that I am trying to convert to Matlab:

```
dunif <- function (x, min = 0, max = 1, log = FALSE) 
.Internal(dunif(x, min, max, log))
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

I would like to know what `.Internal` and `<environment ... >` do.

Thank you much in advance,
Simon

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439348/how-to-examine-the-code-of-a-function-in-r-thats-object-class-sensitive/1444512

Comment: For this specific example it may be helpful to know that the answer is just `1/(max-min)`

Answer (score 20):

From `?.Internal`:

```
 ‘.Internal’ performs a call to an internal code which is built in
 to the R interpreter.
```

You'll find the code for `dunif` in the R sources.  I find this type of function via a grep for it in `main/names.c` then grep for the name it refers to (`do_math3` in this case), which you will find in `main/arithmetic.c`.

`<environment: namespace:stats>` simply tells you the location / namespace of the function.

Answer (score 4):

I found *[R in a Nutshell](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596801717)* a useful resource to explain objects and environments in a non-intimidating way. It is worth a look.