# How can I see what a function inside a function does?

Tags: r, function

I would like to know what the formula for a particular function is.  Usually when I type the function without the parentheses, it returns a formula, so if I type `sd` I will get:

```
function (x, na.rm = FALSE) 
{
    if (is.matrix(x)) 
        apply(x, 2, sd, na.rm = na.rm)
    else if (is.vector(x)) 
        sqrt(var(x, na.rm = na.rm))
    else if (is.data.frame(x)) 
        sapply(x, sd, na.rm = na.rm)
    else sqrt(var(as.vector(x), na.rm = na.rm))
}
<environment: namespace:stats>
```

Which is fine.  But if I were to type `rollmean` with the zoo package loaded it returns this:

```
function (x, k, fill = if (na.pad) NA, na.pad = FALSE, align = c("center", 
    "left", "right"), ...) 
{
    UseMethod("rollmean")
}
<environment: namespace:zoo>
```

I am guessing something is going on in the method `rollmean`, but how do I get to see what is going on in there?  This may be a novice question but I am having a hard time finding out how to see the underlying formula of a particular function.

Comment: You might want to try `?Methods` for a start. Most of the information you need is there.

Comment: Circle 7 of 'The R Inferno' might also be informative in this regard http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf

Comment: @NickSabbe: `?Methods` is for S4 class objects and zoo objects are S3 class objects.  It would be better to start with `?UseMethod` (since that's in the body of the function), then read `?methods` (which is in the See Also section of `?UseMethod`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to examine the code of a function in R that's object class sensitive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439348/how-to-examine-the-code-of-a-function-in-r-thats-object-class-sensitive)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two options :

1) Using the method mechanism, as Nick Sabbe suggests. Notice it is quite hasardous, as it depends greatly on how the class, generic and methods were implemented and in which Object-Oriented framework its was (S3, S4, R5).

```
# List all methods, S3 here
print(methods(rollmean))

  [1] rollmean.default rollmean.ts*     rollmean.zoo*   
  Non-visible functions are asterisked

# Get each of them
getAnywhere("rollmean.default")
getAnywhere("rollmean.ts")
getAnywhere("rollmean.zoo")
```

2) Looking for the R source directly. As it is a package, it is quite easy : find the .tar.gz version of the package, look for the 'R' directory and you will find the source code (with the developper's comments, if any). For zoo : http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/zoo_1.7-6.tar.gz

Answer (score 3):

`rollmean.default` does the trick (as explained in `help(UseMethod)`):

```
function (x, k, na.pad = FALSE, align = c("center", "left", "right"),
...)
{
   x <- unclass(x)
   n <- length(x)
   y <- x[k:n] - x[c(1, 1:(n - k))]
   y[1] <- sum(x[1:k])
   rval <- cumsum(y)/k
   if (na.pad) {
       rval <- switch(match.arg(align), left = {
           c(rval, rep(NA, k - 1))
       }, center = {
           c(rep(NA, floor((k - 1)/2)), rval, rep(NA, ceiling((k -
               1)/2)))
       }, right = {
           c(rep(NA, k - 1), rval)
       })
   }
   return(rval)
}
<environment: namespace:zoo>
```

Comment: doesn't `rollmean.default` only "do the trick" if the class of the object is not of any class "Y" such that `rollmean.Y` exists?

Comment: Yes, @XuWang. Since one expects the basic calculation to be the same for different objects, `fun.default` would be enough for examining the basic algorithm but not for object-specific properties or bugs.

Comment: I would not rely on that logic (or suggest relying on it). Some classes have completely different methods, depending on the function.